# Android payapal integration

Tags: android

this is my first question on stackoverflow.hope i can find my solutuon .i am integrating paypal in android.my device is showing "payment of this marchent are not allowed(invalid client id).here is my code

```
private static final String CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT = PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION;

// note that these credentials will differ between live & sandbox
// environments.
private static final String CONFIG_CLIENT_ID ="my client id";

private static final int REQUEST_CODE_PAYMENT = 1;
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_FUTURE_PAYMENT = 2;

private static PayPalConfiguration config = new PayPalConfiguration()
        .environment(CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT)
        .clientId(CONFIG_CLIENT_ID)
                // The following are only used in PayPalFuturePaymentActivity.
        .merchantName("Rajeev Lochan Sharma")

        .merchantPrivacyPolicyUri(
                Uri.parse("https://www.example.com/privacy"))
        .merchantUserAgreementUri(
                Uri.parse("https://www.example.com/legal"));

PayPalPayment thingToBuy;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_afcl);
    final GlobalClass globalVariable = (GlobalClass) getApplicationContext();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PayPalService.class);
    intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startService(intent);
    ButterKnife.inject(this);
    _request3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // signup();

             new Test().execute(_names.getText().toString(), _placeofbirth.getText().toString(), _timeofbirth.getText().toString()
              );
            thingToBuy = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal("10"), "USD",
                    "quote", PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);
            Intent intent = new Intent(AfcRequest1Activity.this,
                    PaymentActivity.class);

            intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, thingToBuy);

            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_PAYMENT);


        }
    });

}
public void onBackPressed() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert).setTitle("Exit")
            .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish();
                }
            }).setNegativeButton("No", null).show();
}
```

private class Test extends AsyncTask {

```
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        //here you can some progress dialog or some view
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... Params) {
        String res = "";
        try {
            byte[] result = null;
            String str = "";
            HttpClient client;
            HttpPost post;
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePair;
            HashMap<String, String> mData;
            Iterator<String> it;
            HttpResponse response;
            StatusLine statusLine;

            //here is url api call url
            post = new HttpPost("http://astro360horoscope.com/backend/api/form_amc_afc.php");
            nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            mData = new HashMap<String, String>();
            mData.put("username", Params[0]);
            mData.put("placeofbirth", Params[1]);
            mData.put("timeofbirth", Params[2]);

            //for now nothing is there

            it = mData.keySet().iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                String key = it.next();
                nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair(key, mData.get(key)));
            }
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair, "utf-8"));
            client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            response = client.execute(post);
            statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            result = EntityUtils.toByteArray(response.getEntity());
            str = new String(result, "utf-8");
            if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                //here we get the response if all is correct
                res = str;
            } else {
                res = str;
                return res;
            }

        } catch (Exception e1) {
            res = "error:" + e1.getMessage().toString();
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return res;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
        super.onPostExecute(response);



    }
}



public void onFuturePaymentPressed(View pressed) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(AfcRequest1Activity.this,
            PayPalFuturePaymentActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_FUTURE_PAYMENT);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PAYMENT) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            PaymentConfirmation confirm = data
                    .getParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION);
            if (confirm != null) {
                try {
                    System.out.println(confirm.toJSONObject().toString(4));
                    System.out.println(confirm.getPayment().toJSONObject()
                            .toString(4));

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Order placed",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            System.out.println("The user canceled.");
        } else if (resultCode == PaymentActivity.RESULT_EXTRAS_INVALID) {
            System.out
                    .println("An invalid Payment or PayPalConfiguration was submitted. Please see the docs.");
        }
    } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_FUTURE_PAYMENT) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            PayPalAuthorization auth = data
                    .getParcelableExtra(PayPalFuturePaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_AUTHORIZATION);
            if (auth != null) {
                try {
                    Log.i("FuturePaymentExample", auth.toJSONObject()
                            .toString(4));

                    String authorization_code = auth.getAuthorizationCode();
                    Log.i("FuturePaymentExample", authorization_code);

                    sendAuthorizationToServer(auth);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Future Payment code received from PayPal",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("FuturePaymentExample",
                            "an extremely unlikely failure occurred: ", e);
                }
            }
        } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Log.i("FuturePaymentExample", "The user canceled.");
        } else if (resultCode == PayPalFuturePaymentActivity.RESULT_EXTRAS_INVALID) {
            Log.i("FuturePaymentExample",
                    "Probably the attempt to previously start the PayPalService had an invalid PayPalConfiguration. Please see the docs.");
        }
    }
}

private void sendAuthorizationToServer(PayPalAuthorization authorization) {

}

public void onFuturePaymentPurchasePressed(View pressed) {
    // Get the Application Correlation ID from the SDK
    String correlationId = PayPalConfiguration
            .getApplicationCorrelationId(this);

    Log.i("FuturePaymentExample", "Application Correlation ID: "
            + correlationId);

    // TODO: Send correlationId and transaction details to your server for
    // processing with
    // PayPal...
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "App Correlation ID received from SDK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // Stop service when done
    stopService(new Intent(this, PayPalService.class));
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: What is the client_id ? Does it match with the registered id in the dashboard ?

Comment: yes,it is same ..it is not workable in sandbox also